# gwtp programmatically bind presenter and views

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-platform

I have Presenter and two Views ( View1, View2), and have a Constants object (from a property file) with a defaultView() function, how could I bind View1 to te Presenter if the result of the defaultView() function is 1 and View2 in any other results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GWT doesn't have reflection API, you'll need to use [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) . You'll need to write a custom generator.